# WebApi's UrlHelper.Link() does not escape forward slashes (/)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm a bit puzzled by `UrlHelper.Link()` not escaping forward slashes present in `routeValues`, and producing URLs that fail to match the route against which `Link()` generated the URL.  Here is the specific example that I'm experiencing:

I have the following named route template defined:

```
Presentation/{presentationID}/Transition/{SlideIndex}/{playStart}
```

I also have the following code to generate a URL in building a response:

```
this.Url.Link(RouteNameConstants.PresentationTransition,
    new {
        action = ActionNameConstants.PresentationController.Transition,
        presentationId = presentation.PresentationId,  // value: ab/cdefg
        slideIndex = slideIndex,  // value: 1
        playStart = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMilliseconds(-offsetInMilliseconds).Ticks
    }
)
```

... and the result of the call is:

```
http://localhost/Presentation/ab/cdefg/Transition/1/635802956296104590
```

And this, of course, later fails to match the route because it now has an extra segment in the URL for which the original route template doesn't match.  I would expect `UrlHelper.Link()` to produce instead

```
http://localhost/Presentation/ab%2Fcdefg/Transition/1/635802956296104590
```

... which then would match (before urldecode) `presentationID="ab%2Fcdefg"` and subsequently after urldecode to `"presentationID=ab/cdefg"`.

So how come `UrlHelper.Link()` does not escape forward slash `/` to ensure correct link is produced?

Comment: Side note: while theoretically valid, I'd strongly recommend to avoid such values as part of the path as any normalization will likely decode the %2f (i.e. if you ever use `Uri` to hold that value)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes, although that means normalization is broken since only litteral `/` is valid as a separated.  However, I have no control over the id structure, and stuck with what I have, short of moving it to query that I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is around 1.5yrs old but I really can't get away from the double-encoding if I just use Uri.EscapeDataString(). Hence I have put this hack and works for me. Sharing just in case anyone wants a quick answer.

For the sample above

```
var route = Uri.UnescapeDataString(this.Url.Link(
    RouteNameConstants.PresentationTransition,
    new {
        action = "{0}",
        presentationId = "{1}",  // value: ab/cdefg
        slideIndex = "{2}",  // value: 1
        playStart = "{3}"
    }
)); 
// route will be "http://localhost/Presentation/{1}/{0}/{2}/{3}"
// needs `Uri.UnescapeDataString()` as '{' '}' will be encoded

return string.Format(route,
    ActionNameConstants.PresentationController.Transition,
    Uri.EscapeDataString(presentation.PresentationId),
    slideIndex,
    DateTime.UtcNow.AddMilliseconds(-offsetInMilliseconds).Ticks
);
```

Enjoy!